# Triple-cut of a circular doubly linked list, Java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

Given a circular doubly linked list `deck` (possesing field `head`) which has nodes `card` (possessing fields `next` and `prev`), I want to perform a "triple-cut" on the deck, which is defined as picking two cards in the deck and the elements before the first card are replaced with the elements after the second card. The method has to be *`O(1)`.*

My idea is to generate two new circular doubly linked lists deck1 and deck2 and store the left part of the deck and the right part in them, respectively.I made the following picture to better explain what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here follows my coding attempt, the issue arises when trying to slice 'this' deck, and recombining the sliced deck with the new 2 decks in appropriate order.

```
public void tripleCut(Card firstCard, Card secondCard) {
    
    
    // inputs : firstCard = 3H 
    // inputs : secondCard = 2C
    
        // this deck : AC 2D 3H 4D AD 4H 4C AH 2C RJ 3C BJ 3D 2H 

    // deck 3
    Deck d3 = new Deck();
    d3.head = secondCard.next;
    secondCard = d3.head.prev;
    d3.head.prev = this.head.prev;
    
        // d3.head = RJ 
        // d3.head.prev = 2H
    
    //deck 1
    Deck d1 = new Deck();
    d1.head = this.head;
    d1.head.prev = firstCard.prev;

        // d1.head = AC 
        // d1.head.prev = 2D
    
    // Slicing the two decks from 'this' deck

    this.head.prev = secondCard;
    secondCard.next = this.head;
    
    this.head = firstCard;
    firstCard.prev = secondCard;
    this.head.prev = secondCard;
    secondCard.next= this.head;
    
    head.prev.next=d1.head;
    head.prev = d1.head.prev;

}
```

When I try to recombine the decks I get nonsense, suggesting that what I did above is incorrect. How would you guys approach this problem? Even pseudo-code would hewlp, I have been stuck on this for far to long I am really lost.

Comment: two cuts on a circle cannot make it 3 pieces. Can you explain why a and i were not connected?

Comment: @BingWang They aren't connected on the picture but are in the program & I guess you're right but by slicing I mean cutting and recombining the head and tail to make a circle

Comment: if you do not reverse the order it probably ends up like a pretzel shaped. Can you visualize in a picture?

Comment: First, if two cuts make 3 sublists, then the fact that it's circular is just an implementation detail and can be ignored except for adjusting head/tail at the end. It's being treated as non-circular for the purpose of the assignment.  You should be able to do everything just by modifying head/tail and next/previous pointers, no additional lists necessary.  Draw a picture and modify the arrows to figure out how to do it.  If you are given references to the cut nodes this will be _O(1)_.  If you have to find them it'll be _O(n)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clarify on cases

1. left = null and/or right = null
2. left == right == head
3. will left be always before right

### Basic idea

### Cut

#### Assumes head is accessible and left/right order is maintained

1. Three parameters - head, left, right
2. derive tail = head.prev
3. backup beforeLeft = left.prev and afterRight = right.next
4. cut tail, head cycle (tail.next = head.prev = null)
5. cut left.prev = right.next = null, beforeLeft.next = null, afterRight.prev = null

#### Join

1. Six parameters - head, tail, left, right, beforeLeft, afterRight
2. head will move after right (right.next = head, head.prev = right)
3. tail will move before left (left.prev = tail, tail.next = left)
4. set new head and tail (head = afterRight, tail = beforeLeft)
5. join new head and tail (head.prev = tail, tail.next = head)

I have not tested this and its one of the possible approach.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, it works !!!! I have been stuck on this for more than 10 hours .I totally did not consider setting some elements to null, that is very helpful for cutting